# Difference between installing a package with 'apt' and 'pip'

Tags: apt, python3, pip

I have been trying to install a Python module which relies in **setuptools**, and apparently the module was installed using **apt**. However, it seems to be the wrong version, so I tried to install it using **pip** just to see if anything changes (spoiler: nothing changes - apparently).

What are the differences (if any) between the following?

```
pip3 install setuptools
```

and:

```
apt install python3-setuptools
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I will appreciate if someone could explain the differences (if any) between:

Highest level: you never should use `pip install` to install to system (`--system`, or on Linux distros where `--user` isn't the default, omitting `--user`) when things might conflict with your system whereas `apt install` is pretty safe.

Explanation:

`apt` is the package installation tool of your Linux distro. A Linux distribution these days is mostly the effort to offer a way to install packages in a way that works with each other without breaking – for example, if you're trying to install a library that libreoffice uses, but in a version incompatible with your libreoffice, your linux distro tool will tell you that sadly, to fulfill your command, it will have to uninstall libreoffice, because it wouldn't work with that version you're requesting.

The fact that you very rarely see that happen is an indication of how well modern Linux distros are doing here: typically, most of software that you can install using `apt` works well together.

`pip`, on the other hand, has no notion of what other software you have on your machine, which you might need. You tell pip to install something in a version that breaks your ability to even boot your system – it will go ahead and do that.

`pip` is python-specific. It assumes that all there is on that machine that has something to do with Python is kind of "fair game" and can be dealt with arbitrarily. Frankly, that is almost never the case – for example, on Fedora (another Linux distro that you're *not* using), you can easily break the installation tool `dnf` (Fedora's `apt`, if you will) with `pip`.

So, why does `pip` still exist? Well, there *are* situation where it's OK for pip to assume every bit of python it sees is under its control: Python brings a mechanism called *virtual environments*. In these, no python modules are per se installed, and they don't conflict with other software on your machine – simply because other software isn't aware of the environment.

Using that is quite straightforward. You can set up such an environment using

```
python3 -m venv ~/bertsexperiment
```

That sets up a folder `~/bertsexperiment` for Python stuff to be installed into. You can then, from anywhere you like, "activate" that environment (what that really does is just change a few environment variables) – but that only affects the current process and things started from it. Try it:

```
source ~/bertsexperiment/bin/activate
```

will set up this shell in a way that all future python tooling will work with that folder as "prefix".

For example, if you wanted to have an updated setuptools in that shell, you could, after `source`ing the activaton script as shown above, run `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`, and they would be installed into the virtualenv.

In short:

- if in doubt, use `apt`, because it's your distro's job to keep your software stack working together
- Never use `pip` unless you intend to install something into a folder only used for your current project and not by anything else on your system. 
  Hence, the only realistic time you would want to use it is when you're using a Python virtualenv.

Comment: Using `pip` in this case is akin to `make install`: it just moves files around. The problem with both `pip` and `make install` is that it's not the installer that you're supposed to use for your root filesystem. That's what the package manager is for. So using *any* installer to install things into the root filesystem is a bad idea, `pip` being one of many examples. Of course, if your Python installation is _not_ in `/`, but rather in some other location like `/opt/foobar/python3.10`, then using `pip` is perfectly fine. This is what a Python venv does, so using pip in a venv is safe.

Comment: This answer is both factually incorrect and unduly alarmist. Using pip to install Python modules on your own account is fine. You don't have to compartmentalize everything. And on Debian and derivatives (so most distributions using `apt`), `pip install` defaults to user mode. So `pip install foo` will not mess the user's system: only `pip install --system foo` would do that.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thanks for reminding me I simplified a bit, too much maybe. Yes, `--user` installation is sensible, in many cases (not all, to be honest, and if you can get it via `apt`…). I wasn't aware that debian has patched `pip` to default to `--user`! Interesting! Re: Alarmism: I don't think so. I've done a lot of software support, and "how did you install this? Oh, you did a pip system install, and now the binary part of numpy that your C++ libraries linked against is not matching!" is a *very* common theme, in a few variations (throw in CUDA/TensorFlow/PyTorch, pyuhd, …).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' until very recently `pip install` used `--system` by default, which would fail unless the user was running as root. Any reckless novices have broken things by running `sudo pip install`, because that makes the permission errors go away. It's absolutely not alarmist, it's just that Pip has recently taken steps to prevent users from doing this so easily.

Comment: I would recommend these two recent articles on LWN which describe the somewhat unsettling state of Python packaging: <https://lwn.net/Articles/920132/> and <https://lwn.net/Articles/920832/>

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your end goal.

- Something in another Debian package depends on this package? Definitely use `apt`.
- Or conversely, you want to *create* a package or a set of packages for Debian or a Debian-based distro like Ubuntu, Mint, etc - again, definitely stay in `apt` land.
- You want to install something which requires a newer version than you can find on Debian - you can hunt for backported `.deb` packages from https://backports.debian.org/ or random PPAs, but perhaps at this point it's easier and more straightforward to move to `pip`. (Though sometimes the packaging work adds significant value but requires nontrivial effort; then, a PPA can really save your day.)
- You want to develop a Python script of your own and ideally have the latest and greatest features of the Python packages you depend on - usually then use `pip`

  - ... or even install things directly from the upstream Github project or whatever, for the really bleeding edge. But probably don't stretch too far. If you don't have a professional software development team at your disposal, stick to reasonably stable versions for all but the most valuable, most crucial one or two packages you depend on.

To recap, what makes sense ultimately depends on where in the maturity cycle you are. The benefit of official Debian packages is that they tend to be very stable and time-tested, but the drawback is then that you will not be running the latest versions with the spiffiest new features.

Also keep in mind that some Debian packages go to extra lengths to integrate the packaged software with the broader Debian ecosystem. For a random Python script this is typically unimportant, but if it's a Debian system administration tool or some sort of infrastructure project, obviously you want all the Debian parts that upstream might not have, or might not enable and configure correctly by default.