# Software&Updates doesn't launch (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: ubuntu

I have a problem with Software&Updates launching (Ubuntu 22.04).

Syslog:

```
Aug 22 11:07:03 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 systemd[3327]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 dbus-daemon[817]: [system] Activating service name='com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties' requested by ':1.190' (uid=1000 pid=14929 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/software
-properties-gtk " label="unconfined") (using servicehelper)
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 34, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:     from httplib2 import proxy_info_from_environment
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:     from . import auth
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/auth.py", line 4, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:     import pyparsing as pp
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyparsing'
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:   File "/usr/lib/software-properties/software-properties-dbus", line 29, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:     from softwareproperties.dbus.SoftwarePropertiesDBus import (
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/dbus/SoftwarePropertiesDBus.py", line 32, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:     from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 64, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:     from softwareproperties.shortcuts import shortcut_handler
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 23, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:     from softwareproperties.ppa import PPAShortcutHandler
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 25, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:     from launchpadlib.launchpad import Launchpad
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 36, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:     from httplib2 import ProxyInfo
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:     from . import auth
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/auth.py", line 4, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]:     import pyparsing as pp
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[14940]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyparsing'
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 dbus-daemon[817]: [system] Activated service 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties' failed: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:     return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:     return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:     reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties': no such name
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:   File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:     app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 210, in __init__
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:     proxy = bus.get_object("com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties", "/")
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:     return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:     self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:     self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 277, in start_service_by_name
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:     return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]:     reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
Aug 22 11:07:04 maskalev-Aspire-A514-54 software-properties-gtk.desktop[14929]: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

I assume that something is wrong with Python (path, version etc.)

```
maskalev@maskalev-Aspire-A514-54:~$ pip install pyparsing
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.0.9)
maskalev@maskalev-Aspire-A514-54:~$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/maskalev/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
maskalev@maskalev-Aspire-A514-54:~$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
maskalev@maskalev-Aspire-A514-54:~$ ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python2.7         /usr/bin/python3     /usr/bin/python3.10-config  /usr/bin/python3.11-config  /usr/bin/python3-futurize    /usr/bin/python-dotenv
/usr/bin/python2.7-config  /usr/bin/python3.10  /usr/bin/python3.11         /usr/bin/python3-config     /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
```

I will be glad of any advice.
I will send any additional information on request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local user installation isn't relevant to the system software. You can't use pip to install system-wide python packages¹.

Since Ubuntu pretty certainly makes the software center depend on the `python3-pyparsing` package, you must have somehow removed that package (or just its contents?) without `dpkg`/`apt` noticing. The fact that you're attempting to fix this with `pip` gives me the hunch that you somewhere did something like `sudo pip uninstall` and broke your system. You will then most probably encounter more broken things down the way; it's unlikely that removing pyparsing didn't remove other crucial modules as well. Maybe you actually overwrote the `python3` executable that your system uses?

You can try to fix your immediate problem with `sudo apt-get reinstall python3-pyparsing`, but I'm afraid with the multiple versions of python that clutter your path, and if my guess that you have mixed `pip` installations in to your system and thus broke it in ways that are tedious to clean up, your *quickest* solution might be saving your user's home and setting up Ubuntu anew. Your success might really vary, and the amount of time you invest.

---

¹This is exactly the case that I describe [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734792/difference-between-installing-a-package-with-apt-and-pip/734798#734798) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/754506/what-couldve-casued-my-pip-installation-to-disappear-or-at-least-not-be-found/754509#754509), where `pip` has no idea that your system needs some specific version of some specific python module, and breaks your system.