# Install a Python package on Debian/Devuan when apt has no package for it

Tags: debian, package-management, python, pip, devuan

I want to install some Python package `pandasql` system-wide, on a Devuan (or Debian) system. It's in the Python Package Index, but - there doesn't seem to be a (dpkg) package for it; let's assume that there actually isn't.

Now, if I try to `pip install pandasql`, I get a message suggesting I use a virtual environment:

```
× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.
```

... but virtual environments are not what I want to do: I want to install `foo` system-wide. How can I do that?

*Notes*:

- If possible, please answer more generally than just regarding `pandasql`.
- Devuan Excalibur (~= Debian Trixie), Python 3.11.6, x86_64 machine

Comment: Debian doesn't use *apt packages*. We have dpkg. In any case, read the message and do not install python packages in system folders: you will have just problem in future. As the messages: uses virtual environment (so you are independent to the system versions).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Nitpick about apt/dpkg noted. Would you care to please explain why some PyPI packages should not be installed in system folders while others should? I should really not have to setup a virtual environment to run a python script.

Comment: In general you should not mess with system files. apt (dpk) will care about dependencies. If you use pip, the calculation of dependencies cannot be made. But also your script may broke on next system update without warnings. Python and other languages went to insulate own environment. Else you can use `--user`` (and I do not understand why it is not the default), so you install packages only for your user

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: That's not the question I asked. The question is: Why should _some_ PyPI packages not be installed in system folders, while others should. If Debian would decide _no_ packages are installed that would be a different matter.

Comment: Did you give `apt install python3-pandas` a shot yet? Debian tells you to NOT install packages systemwide if they are *not provided by Debian in their repos*.

Comment: What Stephen said, @einpoklum, please don't shift goal posts in the comments. I spend effort on writing the answer to the question that was *actually* asked!

Comment: @StephenKitt: It appeared in my question to Giacomo in the comment, about his earlier comment.

Comment: @einpoklum that's the thing. What gets answered is what is written in the question post. If you want to ask something else, you need to actually do that in the question, not buried in the comments :) That's how this whole confusion happens.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: The question  post and answer posts are just as you say, but comments are a place for further discussion, including questions about points made in previous comments.

Comment: Ah, right, apologies @einpoklum — I misunderstood your second comment as clarifying your overall question, not the question you asked in your first comment. (As far as that goes, *no* unpackaged Python packages should be installed in system directories on Debian. Either package them, as explained in Marcus’ answer, or install them in a virtual environment.)

Comment: @Panki: Indeed I have, and that actually makes me think of another question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fact that Debian won't let you do that does come from somewhere: `pip` system-wide installations are, by design, incompatible with system-managed python installations. [Pip itself has recognized](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/) that when it degraded `--system` installations from "the default" to "the user needs to specify it and hopefully knows what they're doing". Debian knows exactly that you'll break things that way, so it doesn't ship a `pip` that will let you do that.

So much for the theory ([more background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734792/difference-between-installing-a-package-with-apt-and-pip/734798#734798)) of why Debian prevents you from doing that.

Now for the practice:

> What can I do?

So, you need to do what `pip install --system pandasql` does, but do it in a Debian-compatible, safe way, that also doesn't break everything when any dependency is updated. This includes inferring the Debian package names of the dependencies from the pip package, and making it so that if the dependencies change, that you're not left with a dysfunctional package.

To little surprise, the Debian way of installing software are Debian packages. They can be updated, they have a list of dependencies, `dpkg` makes sure they don't overwrite each other's files, they can be cleanly uninstalled. All in all, they, from a whole-system perspective, are nicer than `pip` packages. You want that!

There's a little helper program that does the hard work for you; `sudo apt install pypi2deb`; it's not hard to use:

```bash
mkdir package_pandasql
cd package_pandasql
# Try an initial build
py2dsp --build pandasql
```

If that last step fails with `error: Unmet build dependencies`, that will tell you what you need to install to progress. In my case:

```bash
sudo apt install python3-all python3-numpy python3-pandas python3-setuptools python3-sqlalchemy
```

Let the installation run through and try a second time

```bash
py2dsp --build pandasql
```

That worked!

Now you have an installable package in `package_pandasql/result/`, and you can install it using `sudo apt install ./result/python3-pandasql*.deb`.

Comment: A whole lot of perl sneaks in through the back door with pypi2deb :-P

Comment: @einpoklum no, the perl is completely part of the Debian packaging tools that you also need, either way. pypi2deb is pure python.

Answer (score 3):

As has been noted, there are good reasons why pip no longer lets you install packages system wide, but I also have this use case managing software for large numbers of users who may have access to the same machine and expect software to "just work" without having to have developer knowledge of setting up the software.

When users do try to install things on their own it leads to a lot of different versions being installed, some of them get updated but others don't, and "it works for me but not everyone else" situations. We also use a lot of disk space by having independent copies of large packages for every single user.

A solution that currently works for me in debian:bookworm is to install packages for a special user and group, called `python-global`, and then allow other users to inherit that user's packages by manipulating the `PYTHONPATH` variable.

Installing a package looks like:

```bash
sudo -u python-global python3 -m pip install <x> --break-system-packages
```

And in `/etc/profile.d/python-global.sh` there is this code:

```bash
if [ -z "${__SOURCED_PYTHON_GLOBAL__}" ]; then
    export PYTHONPATH="/home/python-global/python-packages/:$PYTHONPATH";
    export PATH="/home/python-global/.local/bin/:$PATH";
    export __SOURCED_PYTHON_GLOBAL__=1;
fi;
```

Whilst this could still sometimes result in a conflict with a system package, it's relatively easy for a user to disable it by clearing the `PYTHONPATH` variable if they need to. Or they can set `__SOURCED_PYTHON_GLOBAL__` in their own `.profile` to avoid the changes.

You may have to do additional work as `/etc/profile.d` is not automatically sourced, depending on your login manager. You may need to create a copy in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` as well.

If using the flag that is described as "break your system" makes you nervous, you could probably replace the `--break-system-packages` here with a proper virtual environment owned by the `python-global` user. The virtual environment only has to be setup once, and every user uses the same virtual environment.