# Failing to install PyPi package gdown via py2dsp

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, python, py2dsp

On Debian-like/apt-based distributions, instead of installing Python packaged system-wide with `pip install --system`, we use APT packages. Here:

[Install a Python package on Debian/Devuan when apt has no package for it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/761358/34868)

is a discussion on how to do that. Unfortunately, this fails when I try it with the [gdown package](https://pypi.org/project/gdown/):

```
# mkdir /tmp/gdown
# cd /tmp/gdown
# py2dsp --build gdown
W: py2dsp cache:67: cannot load cache (_load_package_names:():{}): unpackb() got an
unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
E: py2dsp py2dsp:172: 'build-system'
```

is this a py2dsp bug? A problem with my own system somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known bug in `py2dsp`](https://bugs.debian.org/1033841), unfortunately with no fix for now.

Pointing `py2dsp` at [the source repository](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown) doesn’t work either, so I suspect the only way forward is to write a source package from scratch using [the source code](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown). To get started:

```
$ curl -Lo gdown-4.7.1.tar.gz https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown/archive/refs/tags/v4.7.1.tar.gz
$ tar xf gdown-4.7.1.tar.gz
$ cd gdown-4.7.1
$ debmake
```

(using the `debmake` package).